# Screen capture does not work if taking a snapshot of the settings panel WHEN the multiple option widget active

Tags: screen, snapshot, capture

I was opening a bug report of the sound settings when I notice that I CANNOT take a snapshot of anything IF the setting windows is open and any of the multiple options widgets are open.

For example,Go to Settings->Sound, click on input device or Output device and then click on print-screen button to bring the snapshot app.

Using ubuntu 22.04 desktop